# gulp browsersync and reload issues

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am new to installing and using gulp, and it's taken me a good few days to get to this part, however, I have learned heaps from my trial and errors, but now I've hit a brick wall.

This is what I have in my **gulpfile.js**:

```js
// MODULES
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var js = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browsersync.reload;
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');



// ERROR LOG
var onError = function (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred:', gutil.colors.magenta(err.message));
    gutil.beep();
    this.emit('end');
};


// COMPILE AND MINIFY SASS
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/css'))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
    done();
});


// MINIFY JS
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/js/*.js')
    .pipe(js())
    .on('error', onError)
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/js/min'))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
    done();
});


// IMAGES
gulp.task('imagemin', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/images'))
    done();
});


// BROWSERSYNC
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: 'http://localhost/testingsite/'
    })
    done();
});

// RELOAD
gulp.task('reload', function (done) {
    browsersync.reload();
    done();
});


// WATCH
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass', 'reload'));
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/js/*.js', gulp.series('js', 'reload'));
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/images/*', gulp.series('imagemin', 'reload'));

    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/**/*.php').on('change', browsersync.reload);
    gulp.watch('*/pixelboutique/**/*.php').on('change', browsersync.reload);
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'js', 'imagemin', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

```js
// MODULES
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var js = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browsersync.reload;
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');



// ERROR LOG
var onError = function (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred:', gutil.colors.magenta(err.message));
    gutil.beep();
    this.emit('end');
};


// COMPILE AND MINIFY SASS
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/css'))
    // .pipe(browsersync.stream())
    done();
});


// MINIFY JS
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/js/*.js')
    .pipe(js())
    .on('error', onError)
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/js/min'))
    // .pipe(browsersync.stream())
    done();
});


// IMAGES
gulp.task('imagemin', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/images'))
    done();
});


// BROWSERSYNC
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: 'http://localhost/testingsite/'
    })
    done();
});

// RELOAD
gulp.task('reload', function (done) {
    browsersync.reload()
    done();
});


// WATCH
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass', 'reload'));
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/js/*.js', gulp.series('js', 'reload'));
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/images/*', gulp.series('imagemin', 'reload'));

    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/pixelboutique/**/*.php').on('change', browsersync.reload);
    gulp.watch('*/pixelboutique/**/*.php').on('change', browsersync.reload);
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'js', 'imagemin', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

and this is the output in terminal:

```
$ gulp
[12:43:31] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\testingsite\gulpfile.js
[12:43:31] Starting 'default'...
[12:43:31] Starting 'sass'...
[12:43:31] Finished 'sass' after 300 ms
[12:43:31] Starting 'js'...
[12:43:32] Finished 'js' after 241 ms
[12:43:32] Starting 'imagemin'...
[12:43:32] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
[12:43:32] Finished 'imagemin' after 11 ms
[12:43:32] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[12:43:32] Finished 'browser-sync' after 72 ms
[12:43:32] Starting 'watch'...
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/testingsite/
    External: http://192.168.0.37:3000/testingsite/
 --------------------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------------------
[12:43:40] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 2 files changed (style.css, woocommerce.css)
[12:43:40] Finished 'sass' after 266 ms
[12:43:40] Starting 'reload'...
[12:43:40] Finished 'reload' after 796 μs
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[12:43:49] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 2 files changed (style.css, woocommerce.css)
[12:43:49] Finished 'sass' after 203 ms
[12:43:49] Starting 'reload'...
[12:43:49] Finished 'reload' after 371 μs
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[12:43:51] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 2 files changed (style.css, woocommerce.css)
[12:43:51] Finished 'sass' after 206 ms
[12:43:51] Starting 'reload'...
[12:43:51] Finished 'reload' after 458 μs
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[12:44:00] Starting 'js'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (all.min.js)
[12:44:00] Finished 'js' after 167 ms
[12:44:00] Starting 'reload'...
[12:44:00] Finished 'reload' after 431 μs
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

My file changes in sass, js and php are watched and the browser refreshes, but the js and sass aren't injected into the site. The php changes are reloaded and injected ok.

Comment: You do have both a `reload` call in your scss `watch` task and a `stream` call at the end of your `sass` task.  Could be confusing gulp?  Get rid of the `watch` task one.  Are you saying when you make a scss change the `js` task runs?

Comment: Instead of `browsersync.stream()` you could try `    .pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream: true }));` to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried that and no change.
When I change my style.scss, it runs but says that all of my styles.scss files have changed and when I change a .js file, it runs and says that all of my .js files have changes. I'm not sure if that's correct?

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was adsblock extension was blocking the browsersync reload, make sure to turn it off on the specific page. I even had to close the browser and open it again to make sure it was completely turned off.